# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers Magento2.1.9

Tags: database, magento-2.1.9

I am getting **Server sent charset unknown** error during setting up magento 2.1.9 on localhost.

PHP version - 5.6 or 7.1, 
MySQL version - 8.0

I tried to add in **my.cnf**

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8


[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

but it is not working.

Is there any other fix for the issue?

Comment: have you tried commenting this char-sets?